# Stabilization of telescope on gimbal using data from encoders and gyroscope

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory, matlab

I'm designing a control system for a balloon-borne telescope experiment. As the balloon is constantly moving and the gondola is rotating, I want to stabilize the telescope which can be controlled in 3 axis of rotation. I have encoders for each axis motors and gyroscope located on the electronics box around 20cm apart from the telescope's center of rotation.

Is there a possibility of performing a sensor fusion, like Kalman filter, for these two groups of sensors?

I have a prepared model of the control loop, but have then realized that the sensors are in different places and while gyroscopes measure gondola movement, the encoders measure the telescope rotation.

[image]

Comment: What have you searched for so far? how do camera stabilisation platforms work?

Comment: From what I have found the gyroscopes (or the IMU in general) is usually located on the camera, so I couldn't find anything that would apply to my case.

Comment: shockless camera mounts usually have the camera mounted onto them...

Comment: NASA has a public code for this job. It handles all kinds of nested telemetry, orientation, and control functions for an orbiting satellite systems, provides standardized nomenclature for body references, and handles all the astronomical targeting for nearly everything up there. (Was tough to find, I think this will get you started - https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/naif/cosmographia.html)

Comment: KVH Industries has already perfected the technology for doing what you are trying to do, they have a dynamic satellite tracking system for ocean vessels that locks onto the transmitting satellite of interest and locks onto it regardless of how the ship is rocking on the ocean waves. Now all you have to do is get ahold of their electronic schematics ,  LOL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're getting confused because you're trying to combine the gyroscopes and encoders into one data source.

An easier way would be to calculate an angular deflection in each axis using your gyros. Now lets call wherever the telescope is pointing "zero". The gyroscope provides a target angle that is necessary to maintain "zero", and the motors and encoders will use PID to try to stay at that angle.

Also, the stars are far away, so you can probably just pretend your gyro and telescope exist at a single point.